# Arriving in Dubai T1, where should I meet a friend flying into T3?

Tags: air-travel, dxb

My flight is to land at dubai t1 and one of my friend flight is about to land at t3 after 1 hour.Can I wait for him inside the airport, if so where?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are going to Dubai (and not transiting to another destination).

There is a coffee shop near the entrance to the metro station, inside Terminal 3. There is plenty of seating in this area and there is free wifi. It would be a good place to meet. You can take the metro from Terminal 1 to Terminal 3.